# Windows 10 app (.appx) having data in pocuhDB for offline storage getting cleaned up once system is restarted

Tags: pouchdb

I have a windows 10 app that is a hybrid application based on cordova  and HTML5. It used pouchDB for storing data in offline storage.
it has Sync feature that is started after user signs up in the app and it downloads app data and stores it in pouchDB for offline storage. 
Now if user closes the app and restarts the windows 10 machine where app is installed, launching the app again pouchDB data earlier stored would be lost and no more be available to the app.

Application data in Offline storage(pouchDB) should be retained after system restarts.

Comment: did anyone already face this issue, though android version of the same app is working fine as expected?